# Can't get titanium to print console messages to a native Iphone console

Tags: ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-alloy

For example:

```
Ti.API.info("My log message")
```

I am trying to print this into an **actual device console** on my iphone. (It works fine for the simulator console)

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Native_iOS_Debugging_and_Testing_Tools

As shown here.

However, within the native iphone console, Ti.API.info("My log message") never gets printed. Only native ios based logs.

I have tired everything from changing the log levels in the simulator to "debug", without success.

I have tried Iphone configuration utility and Xcode organizer console.

Comment: Try `console.log()`. Also check if you haven't overwrite Ti.API.info function by accident. What Titanium SDK version are you using?

Comment: Ive tried console.log - only prints out in simulator console. Using sdk version 3.2.3 GA

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this? I seem to have the same problem... using 5.2.2.GA and iOS 9.3.2 device.